# OLEDB query to select first and last time for id

Tags: excel, vba, oledb, adodb

I'm using ADODB connection in VBA excel file with Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider.
The file with which I'm establishing connection is .csv file which looks like:

```
Date and time, Last name, First name
2011-08-29  05:48:50,lname1,fname1
2011-08-29  05:49:50,lname1,fname1
2011-08-29  05:55:50,lname2,fname2
2011-08-29  16:11:50,lname1,fname1
2011-08-29  17:55:50,lname2,fname2
2011-08-30  9:11:50,lname1,fname1
```

The point is that my data is sorted by `Date and time` which is in one field, and user names are not in any order. 
What I really need to do is create a query to fill `Recordset`.

I need this query to **select first, second and last hour for each day for each user name**.
Is it even possible to split `Date and time` column just using a query? 
I've got general idea how to select what I want, but the thing is too complicated for me, because of that Date and time in the same field.

Would you give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say your file is called Dates.csv, you can try:

```
SELECT 
   [Last name] & ", " & [First Name] AS FullName, 
   Format([Date And time],"yyyy/mm/dd") AS WorkingDay, 
   First(Format([Date And time],"hh:nn:ss")) AS FirstHour, 
   Last(Format([Date And time],"hh:nn:ss")) AS LastHour
FROM [Dates.csv]
GROUP BY [Last name] & ", " & [First Name], Format([Date And time],"yyyy/mm/dd")
```

I am a little suspicious of the double space between date and time. I would get rid of the spaces in the column names, if I were you. It will make things easier.